# Is there any book/books dedicated to Jquery & Sharepoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

Im buliding metrics using the "content web editor" component on Sharepoint 2007. Im using Jquery/JavaScript to write the code.

Is there any book/books dedicated to Jquery/JavaScript & Sharepoint ?

Comment: If only there was a large online bookstore one could search to find this answer.... http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=jquery+sharepoint

Answer (score 2):

Wrox has a [SharePoint book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470584645) with an entire chapter on jQuery, but it's for SharePoint 2010.

Another book called [Pro SharePoint with jQuery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430240989) won't be out until Feb 2012.

There's also [this jQuery library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) which claims to simplify things.

Comment: Just to add 'Pro SharePoint with jQuery' is now out